# layout backActivity Problem

Tags: android

i have text.xml file which contain two layout one is for image view and second is for display text. i am displaying text in both layout using edit-text which is popup layout. it will display correctly in both layout textview and imageview but the problem is when i move from text.xml to setting.xml and again back to text.xml from setting.xml then text will not appear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use saving the display text in the onSaveInstanceState method and using it again while returning to the activity by  onRestoreInstanceState method.